# PostgreSQL tables appear empty in Django

Tags: django, postgresql

I restored PostgreSQL on pythonanywhere from sql-formatted pg-dump made on my macbook.
My tables appear healthy in PostgreSQL, but they appear empty in Django.
I suspect I have two schemas or two databases, and the one Django is looking at is empty.

```
DATABASES = {
  'default': {
      'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
      'NAME': 'mydb2',
      'USER': 'super',
      'PASSWORD': 'bigsecretR4',
      'HOST': 'magula6-1249.postgres.pythonanywhere-services.com',
      'PORT': '11249',
      'OPTIONS': {
        'connect_timeout': 60,
      }

  }
```

}

```
postgres=# select count(*) from public.cw_city5;
count 
-------
 615

>>> from cw.models import *
>>> qs=City5.objects.all()
>>> len(qs)
0
```

Comment: did you run the `python manage.py makemigrations` in pythonanywhere bash ?

Comment: `\l` will list database in `psql`. Can you post the connection string you're using to start `psql`? Is it possible that you're connecting to your local postgres instance through psql?

Comment: Thanks jimijimjim. I did: postgres=# \l as you suggested and saw there were four names, then changed the NAME in Django DATABASES settings to 'postgres' and voilà!